# A poker hand contains five cards. Find the probability that a poker hand can be…

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

d) one pair

Since there are 13 ranks, we pick 1 rank. $\binom{13}{1}$, for each of these ways we want to pick 2 cards out of 4 that belong in this rank. So $\binom{13}{1} \binom{4}{2}$. Now we want 3 other cards where their face values are different, but their ranks can be the same? But if we pick from 13 ranks, that'll include a card that may have been picked already. So we pick 3 from 12 remaining ranks, $\binom{12}{3}$ and for each of these ways, we want to pick 1 card out of 4, 3 times. So the total number of ways is:

$$\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{12}{3}\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{1}$$

And then the probability would just be the result after we divide by $$\binom{52}{5}$$

Is this correct?

e) two pairs

13 ranks, choose 2 ranks out of 13. For each of these ways, we pick 2 cards out of 4. And then want 1 last card that that can technically be any rank but needs to have a different face value. But if we do $\binom{13}{1}$ that might count a card that was already picked? So do we pick from 11 ranks instead? $\binom{11}{1}$ and for each of these ways we have $\binom{4}{1}$ ways to pick 1 card. So the total number of ways is:

$$\binom{13}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{11}{1}\binom{4}{1}$$

And then divide by $$\binom{52}{5}$$ to get the probability?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your first solution is correct.  Your only error in the second problem is that you did not select two cards from each rank from which a pair is drawn.

> What is the probability of drawing two pairs?

As you said, we must choose $2$ of the $13$ ranks from which a pair will be drawn.  For each of these two ranks, we must select two of the four cards.  From the remaining $11$ ranks, we must choose a rank from which a single card will be drawn.  We must also choose one of the four cards of that rank.  Therefore, the probability of drawing two pairs when selecting a five-card hand from a standard deck is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{13}{2}\dbinom{4}{2}^2\dbinom{11}{1}\dbinom{4}{1}}{\dbinom{52}{5}}$$